# SQLite database Error cannot find column studentName

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Help iv'e been tying to use sqlite db but the db is not allowing new record entries. Here is my error log. Error Log:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table students has no column named studentName
11-30 12:56:01.576 11160-11160/com.webutu.cordiscorp.schoolbus E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting studentName=ADE sex=HD address=QS status=SAHDB studentClass=SAHDB parentNo=908 studentParent=K
                                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table students has no column named studentName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO students(studentName,sex,address,status,studentClass,parentNo,studentParent) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                                     at com.webutu.cordiscorp.schoolbus.Attendance.DatabaseHandler.addStudent(DatabaseHandler.java:70)
                                                                                     at com.webutu.cordiscorp.schoolbus.AttendanceFragment$2.onClick(AttendanceFragment.java:112)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my DatabaseHander.class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final  int DATABASE_VERSION  = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME   = "studentsAttendance";
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS  = "students";

    private static final String KEY_ID          = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME        = "studentName";
    private static final String KEY_CLASS       = "studentClass";
    private static final String KEY_PARENT      = "studentParent";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS      = "status";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS     = "address";
    private static final String KEY_PARENT_NO   = "parentNo";
    private static final String KEY_SEX         = "sex";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //create db
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                +TABLE_STUDENTS+ "("
                +KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                +KEY_NAME +"TEXT,"
                +KEY_CLASS + "TEXT,"
                +KEY_PARENT + "TEXT,"
                +KEY_STATUS + "TEXT,"
                +KEY_ADDRESS+ "TEXT,"
                +KEY_SEX+ "TEXT,"
                +KEY_PARENT_NO+"TEXT"+");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE);
    }

    //upgrade db
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_STUDENTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add new student
    public void addStudent(Student student){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME,student.get_studentName());
        values.put(KEY_CLASS,student.get_studentClass());
        values.put(KEY_PARENT,student.get_studentParent());
        values.put(KEY_SEX,student.get_sex());
        values.put(KEY_STATUS,student.get_status());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS,student.get_address());
        values.put(KEY_PARENT_NO,student.get_parentNo());
        db.insert(TABLE_STUDENTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
}

 Student.class

public class Student {
    private  int _id;
    private  String _studentName;
    private  String _studentClass;
    private  String _studentParent;
    private  String _status;
    private  String _address;
    private  String _parentNo;
    private  String _sex;


    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(int id, String studentName, String studentClass, String studentParent, String status, String sex, String address, String parentNo){
        this._id = id;
        this._studentName = studentName;
        this._studentClass = studentClass;
        this._studentParent = studentParent;
        this._status = status;
        this._address = address;
        this._sex = sex;
        this._parentNo = parentNo;
    }
    public Student(String studentName, String studentClass, String studentParent, String status, String address,String sex, String parentNo){
        this._studentName = studentName;
        this._studentClass = studentClass;
        this._studentParent = studentParent;
        this._status = status;
        this._sex = sex;
        this._address = address;
        this._parentNo = parentNo;
    }


    public int getID(){
       return this._id;
    }
    public  void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    public String get_studentName(){
        return this._studentName;
    }
    public  void set_studentName(String studentName){
        this._studentName = studentName;
    }
    public String get_studentClass(){
        return this._studentClass;
    }
    public  void set_studentClass(String studentClass){
        this._studentClass = studentClass;
    }
    public String get_studentParent(){
        return this._studentParent;
    }
    public  void set_studentParent(String studentParent){
        this._studentParent = studentParent;
    }
    public String get_status(){
        return this._status;
    }
    public  void set_status(String status){
        this._status =  status;
    }
    public String get_sex(){
        return this._sex;
    }
    public  void set_sex(String sex){
        this._sex = sex;
    }
    public String get_address(){
        return this._address;
    }
    public  void set_address(String address){
        this._address = address;
    }
    public String get_parentNo(){
        return this._parentNo;
    }
    public  void set_parentNo(String parentNo){
        this._parentNo = parentNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: change db version and run

Comment: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.* please do not "eat" spaces ... obviously your table has columns like idINTEGER, nameTEXT ...

Comment: already done that still the same error @Mohd Saquib

Comment: Please check you db, tables and field name again. I hope you got your error. it's mismatch issue

Answer (score 1):

change your create table query because it has no space where needed. after run again your insert in app.

```
String CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TABLE_STUDENTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_NAME +" TEXT, "
                + KEY_CLASS + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PARENT + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_SEX + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PARENT_NO +" TEXT );";
```